# How to initialize UIColor with white color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am trying to initialize `UIColor` instance with `whiteColor` and I am not able to do it. The screen appears black if I do this:

```
color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

But below line works fine ...

```
color = [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0/255.0 
                        green:169.0/255.0 
                         blue:140.0/255.0 
                        alpha:1.0];
```

I am sure I am doing something stupid, any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Thanks, Oh I didn't knew this. Anyway I solved it by  [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((0xFFFFFF & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((0xFFFFFF & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)( & 0xFFFFFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 11):

Your code `color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]` should work just fine. Could it be that you forgot a semicolon in the end?

Comment: No otherwise, The compilation wouldn't have gone through.

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy, just use this function:

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f 
                                  green:204/255.0f 
                                   blue:0/255.0f 
                                  alpha:1.0f];
```

You can use an online tool to get the RGB components or get a code that can be used to initialize UIColor.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

You can also find a list of all preset component values supported by UIColor objects [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

When using the colorWithWhite method on UIColor, the first parameter is a grayscale value to be applied to the color.  Thus, when you provide a 1.0 value, you are turning the color to black (providing an alpha of 1.0).  for white, you would provide a 0.0 value for the first parameter.

Comment: Can you include the code you are using or the whole method where the code exists?

Comment: So after trying this on an iOS 9.1 simulator, here are the results.

This code will provide a solid white color:
`[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]`

This code will provide a solid black color:
`[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0]`

From further reading, the alpha works just as one would expect, it will allow the background to blend into the desired color.  The first float provides a grayscale value inverse to white.  Thus, a float of 1.0 yields a pure white color.  A float value of 0.0 yields black.  A float value of 0.5 yields a gray.  Changing the alpha value will change that up.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 3** it is like this

`UIColor.white`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.x**

```
UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Any (CG object) = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.